# Count days till a specific column meets specific criteria in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe looks like this

| Serialnr | Date | Event occured |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.01.22 | 0 |
| 1 | 05.02.22 | 0 |
| 1 | 12.02.22 | 1 |
| 1 | 20.04.22 | 0 |
| 1 | 27.04.22 | 0 |
| 1 | 01.05.22 | 0 |
| 1 | 05.05.22 | 1 |
| 2 | 10.01.22 | 0 |
| 2 | 05.02.22 | 0 |
| 2 | 12.02.22 | 1 |
| 2 | 20.04.22 | 0 |
| 2 | 27.04.22 | 0 |
| 2 | 01.05.22 | 0 |
| 2 | 05.05.22 | 1 |

And I have to count the days in each line the number of days left until the event occurs for the specific serialnumber.
I want the column 'Days_to_event', like this:

| Serialnr | Date | Event occured | Days_to_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.01.22 | 0 | 33 |
| 1 | 05.02.22 | 0 | 7 |
| 1 | 12.02.22 | 1 | 82 |
| 1 | 20.04.22 | 0 | 15 |
| 1 | 27.04.22 | 0 | ... |
| 1 | 01.05.22 | 0 | ... |
| 1 | 05.05.22 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 10.01.22 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 05.02.22 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 12.02.22 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 20.04.22 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 27.04.22 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 01.05.22 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 05.05.22 | 1 | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html)/[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

m = df['Event occured'].eq(1)
next_event = (df['Date'].where(m).groupby(df['Serialnr'])
              .transform(lambda g: g.bfill().shift(-1))
             )

df['Days_to_event'] = df['Date'].rsub(next_event).dt.days
```

Output:

```
    Serialnr       Date  Event occured  Days_to_event
0          1 2022-01-10              0           33.0
1          1 2022-02-05              0            7.0
2          1 2022-02-12              1           82.0
3          1 2022-04-20              0           15.0
4          1 2022-04-27              0            8.0
5          1 2022-05-01              0            4.0
6          1 2022-05-05              1            NaN
7          2 2022-01-10              0           33.0
8          2 2022-02-05              0            7.0
9          2 2022-02-12              1           82.0
10         2 2022-04-20              0           15.0
11         2 2022-04-27              0            8.0
12         2 2022-05-01              0            4.0
13         2 2022-05-05              1            NaN
```

##### handling the last event

If you want the last reference to be the max date instead of NaNs:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

m = df['Event occured'].eq(1)
next_event = (df.groupby(df['Serialnr'])['Date']
              .transform(lambda g: g.where(m).bfill().shift(-1).fillna(g.max()))
             )

df['Days_to_event'] = df['Date'].rsub(next_event).dt.days
```

Output:

```
    Serialnr       Date  Event occured  Days_to_event
0          1 2022-01-10              0             33
1          1 2022-02-05              0              7
2          1 2022-02-12              1             82
3          1 2022-04-20              0             15
4          1 2022-04-27              0              8
5          1 2022-05-01              0              4
6          1 2022-05-05              1              2
7          1 2022-05-07              0              0
8          2 2022-01-10              0             33
9          2 2022-02-05              0              7
10         2 2022-02-12              1             82
11         2 2022-04-20              0             15
12         2 2022-04-27              0              8
13         2 2022-05-01              0              4
14         2 2022-05-05              1              0
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But what can I do when I want to have instead of NaN, where is no next event that it counts till the last date in the group?

Comment: The last date of the groups is the date of the row, right? Then the value is 0? You can add `fillna(0, downcast='infer')` Or use `g.bfill().shift(-1, fill_value='0')` in the `transform`.

Comment: NB. I failed to mention it, but my solution assumes that the dates are sorted (per group).

Comment: Yes they are sorted per group. But sometimes there are more lines within a group after an event (when the new event is not occured yet) And then it should count to the last date in the group

Comment: I see, should be easy to handle. Let me update this a bit later (busy now) ;)

Comment: @lis see update. I added an extra row as example